# Allow Magento shipping methods with recurring profile

Tags: php, magento

I've installed a plugin that enables a custom shipping method into my store (calculates shipping method with my postal service). 
It works with any product, except those with recurring profile enabled.

I found this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/Magento-Knowledge-Base-Working-with-Recurring-Profiles saying:

> ... For products with recurring profiles, the customer can only choose
>   between the fixed-price shipping methods (flat, table or free) when
>   checking out. ...

Why there is this rule? How can I make my custom shipping method work with recurring profile products?

I've tried these plugins and both doesn't work.

https://github.com/pedro-teixeira/correios

https://github.com/willstorm/correios

Which files should I look at to edit to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you need to basically change your shipping method class in order to add this:

```
class Namespace_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Customrate
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected $_code = 'my_customrate';
    protected $_isFixed = true; // << THIS ONE 
...
}
```